Defining margin in measure theoretic probability.
This probably seems a dumb question. Anyway, let $\mathbb{P}(X, Y)$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What would be a proper definition of the marginal distribution of $\mathbb{P}$? I think one can take it as $\mathbb{P}_X(X):=\int 1d\mathbb{P}(X, \cdot)$, where $1$ simply means a constant. Is this correct? X and Y shall be taken as measurable sets from $\mathbb{R}$.

What does it mean to say $\mathbb{P}(x, y)$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Edited. Thank you for your reminder.

If $\mu$ is a measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}_X \otimes \mathcal{T}_Y$ on $X\times Y$, then the map $A \mapsto \mu(A\times Y)$ is a measure on $\mathcal{T}_X$, and it is this measure that is called the marginal (on $X$) measure of $\mu$.
